# How to pass a countdown latch to an Apache Storm/Trident Filter without incurring a not-serializable exception

Tags: java, apache-storm, trident

I'm trying to create some tests to verify data going through an Apache Storm topology (using the Trident API)

I've created this simple filter to access callbacks:

```
public class CallbackFilter extends BaseFilter {

    private final TupleCallback callback;

    public CallbackFilter(TupleCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isKeep(TridentTuple tuple) {
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.callback(tuple);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public interface TupleCallback extends Serializable{
        void callback(TridentTuple tuple);
    }
}
```

If I try this, I get a runtime exception saying CountdownLatch is not serializable:

```
    @Test
    public void testState() throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(4);
        TridentTopology tridentTopology = new TridentTopology();
        FeederBatchSpout spout = ...
        TridentState state = ...
        // problematic code:
        CallbackFilter.TupleCallback callback = (CallbackFilter.TupleCallback & Serializable) tuple -> {
            System.out.println("tuple = " + tuple);
            latch.countDown();  //latch is not serializable - exception!
        };
        CallbackFilter latchFilter = new CallbackFilter(callback);
        tridentTopology.stuff()
          .each(new Fields("foo", "bar"), latchFilter);
        ...
```

So it appears Storm is serializing all of the components of a topology and then submitting them in the serialized form, probably for clustering or whatnot.

Is there any way of getting a callback from Storm to the calling test?   Maybe some sort of test mode that doesn't serialize the topology?  It's kinda hard to see what is going on inside the topology from a test point of view, especially at each stage of a topology.

update:

even doing something like this doesn't work!

```
    List<TridentTuple> tupleList = new ArrayList<>();
    CallbackFilter.TupleCallback callback = (CallbackFilter.TupleCallback & Serializable) tuple -> {
        tupleList.add(tuple);
    };
```

I see the tupleList being added to in the debugger, but in the space of the test, the list stays zero.   It's like the topology is running in its own JVM.

Comment: Do you use `LocalCluster`?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - yes, I'm using LocalCluster.

Comment: There is no second JVM. However, Storm creates a new instance of each spout/bolt in the topology. You can make a member variable static. Take care to proper synchrimize the access to it if parallelism is larger than 1. Hope this helps.